# ASP.NET MVC DateTime value not saving when posted after failed vaildation

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a form that requires 2 dates to be entered. One must be after the other. I have a custom validator set up to handle this. If the later date is invalid, the validator triggers and shows an error message as expected. If the date is then corrected to a valid date, it gets posted to the server as "01/01/0001". The corrected date does not make it to the server.

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Start")]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "End")]
[CustomTimeRangeEnd(ErrorMessage = "End Date is required and must be a valid date after Start Date")]
public DateTime End { get; set; }
```

Validator:

```
public class CustomTimeRangeEndAttribute : ModelAwareValidationAttribute
{
    static CustomTimeRangeEndAttribute()
    {
        Register.Attribute(typeof(CustomTimeRangeEndAttribute));
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value, object container)
    {
        var model = (ICustomTimeRange)container;

        if (value == null) return false;

        DateTime dt;
        var validdt = DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt);

        if (!validdt) return false;

        if (dt < model.Start) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Start, new { @class = "control-label" })<br />
<input type="date" name="Start" id="Start" />

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.End, new { @class = "control-label" })<br />
<input type="date" name="End" id="End" />
```

Comment: To clarify, both dates make it to the sever on the initial post?  Does the name or id attribute of the HTML date input get altered when there is a validation error?

Comment: Yes, both make it to the server on initial post. The name and id attributes do not change if there is an error.

Comment: @RossD `it gets posted to the server as "01/01/0001".`- it means your value is not passing from view to controller.

Comment: Better to provide controller action and `ICustomTimeRange` definition, because some important information to reproduce the issue are still missing. As far as I know the `date` input by default has `yyyy-MM-dd` format, but you're stating `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @TanvirArjel said If it is posted as "01.01.0001" you have problem in your view. If you are using datepicker check their time format you can add to your code

```
dateformat:'dd-mm-yy'
```

to provide it. like

```
$('#end').datepicker({
dateformat:'dd-mm-yy'
});
```